# Subversion svn info says directory is on an old revision but code is new

Tags: svn, version-control

I've got a svn linked directory that multiple users are working on. The other day I typed `svn info` and saw that the last revision (rev: 100) was from a month ago, about 4 commits from the most recent code (rev: 104). I was wondering why someone had decided to update back ton that old revision. However, upon further investigation, I realized that the code was actually the most recent code despite `svn info` saying that the code was from a revision 4 commits ago. `svn status` did not mark any of the files with code differences between rev 100 and 104 as "Modified". If I had not looked into the specific files, I could only assume that the code was old from rev: 100. I tried `svn update` and it brought `svn info`'s revision number past the most recent revision to rev: 105, so now `svn info` gives an accurate revision number. There was no changes to any of the code. However, I'm wondering what might be the reason why an old revision number would show up in `svn info` and if there is a way to avoid that from happening again? I guess I could always do `svn update` but sometimes maybe I don't want to if I'm working on something. Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

`svn info` executed inside a working copy is a local operation, i.e. it will never contact the repository for up-to-date information but will provide all data based on the working copy's current state. Thus if you want to see the state of a particular resource *in the repository*, you must either first run `svn update` (as you did) or you need to provide a repository URL as the `TARGET` argument.

For example, to get the current info for the working copy folder you are in, you can use the following command:

```
svn info `svn info | grep ^URL: | awk '{print $2}'`
```